# Async task method issue on a linq query return in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, async-await, entity-framework-4

I need help here with async tasks I am trying to return a list of values coming from a database and I have a table repository and then using a irepository of that class, the issue I am having is using my async task in my method to return the list of values.

Here is my code, my problem here is how to properly use the async tasks and then the await in the return for my linq query in the method because I get an error GetMaterialLookupCodeQuery()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BarcodeReceivingApp.Core.Repositories;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp.Persistence.Repositories
{
    public class MaterialRepository : Repository<Material>, IMaterialRepository
    {
        public MaterialRepository(BarcodeReceivingDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetMaterialLookupCodeQuery()
        {
            return await BarcodeReceivingDbContext.Materials.Include(m => m.MaterialLookupCode).Select(m => m.MaterialLookupCode);
        }

        public BarcodeReceivingDbContext BarcodeReceivingDbContext
        {
            get { return Context as BarcodeReceivingDbContext; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the interface of the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp.Core.Repositories
{
    public interface IMaterialRepository : IRepository<Material>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetMaterialLookupCodeQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: can someone take a look at this issue?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Here is the error message `Error CS1061 'IQueryable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I have seen that error before while doing google search but I could not find a solution for my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq uses the keyword `yield return` and this denotes that we won't actually do the operation until it's called upon. So your avoid code is trying to await the operation of a lazily invoked method.

per this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

`Although it's less code, take care when mixing LINQ with asynchronous code. Because LINQ uses deferred (lazy) execution, async calls won't happen immediately as they do in a foreach() loop unless you force the generated sequence to iterate with a call to .ToList() or .ToArray().`

So, lose the wait. You're not actually executing the statement until the results are used

Comment: Can you write as an example how then my GetMaterialLookupCodeQuery method should be change? also, if I remove the await then should I also remove the async Task in the method?

Comment: Remove the async, and the Task

Comment: But the problem comes that when loading select statement I am using there in my method it takes 5 to 10 seconds to load the list in the form and freezes while loading the material list what should I to prevent that since I can't use async?

Comment: Leave the await then and then run to list at the end to instantly yield the statement or, run this on a separate thread.

Comment: I tried this and I get an error, please review it and let me know how should I write it `public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetMaterialLookupCodeQuery()
        {        
            return await BarcodeReceivingDbContext.Materials
                        .Include(m => m.MaterialLookupCode)
                        .Select(m => m.MaterialLookupCode)
                        .ToList();
        }`

Comment: thanks, your solution gave me an idea that fixed my issue thanks.